# How to make a list of images responsive to window size - CSS/JS/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this code:

```
<ul class="acc-list list-inline">
    <li>
        <img src="image.png" alt="">
        <div class="item-container">
            <p class="description">texttexttext</p>
            <p class="name">texttexttext</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image.png" alt="">
        <div class="item-container">
            <p class="description">texttexttext</p>
            <p class="name">texttexttext</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image.png" alt="">
        <div class="item-container">
            <p class="description">texttexttext</p>
            <p class="name">texttexttext</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With Bootstrap and some additional CSS, this code is essentially producing a list of 3 images horizontally across the page. The images are nothing special and as I'm using bootstrap they reposition themselves when resizing the window slightly. If I resize my window to represent something similar to a mobile phone screen for example, because of my styling and bootstrap the list simple shows all 3 images on top of each other vertically.

Great you may think, but what I want to do in this scenario is actually use some sort of jQuery slider gallery instead. Instead of the images lining up vertically on top of each other in a smartphone size window, I would like them to go away and come back as a slider gallery.

I have tried, but admittedly I really suck at jQuery/JS, so I'm wandering if anyone can point me towards a good example of this or can help with some coding. I've looked around on the internet but I only seem to come across examples of the slider resizing with the window.

However, what I want to do is completely get rid of my list code and throw these images into an entirely new slider gallery when the window is very small.

Comment: Without constructing all the elements you'd need using JS, you can have the slider and the list you provided in the DOM at load. You'd then toggle visibility:visible/hidden on the elements based on the window width using $(window).width()

Comment: Thanks @DaveBriand, is there any specific width you would recommend for something like this? Or a slider you recommend, I looked at some but with limited JS experience they looked rather difficult if I'm honest.

Comment: if you're already using bootstrap you can take a look at the slider included in that - I don't use sliders ever so I'm not sure which ones work well. As for the width, you should spend some time playing with the bootstrap grid - it divides elements into 12 columns and uses percentages to calculate columns widths. Once you start playing with it you'll get it.

Comment: I understand how bootstrap and the css/html behind it works, but I'm really struggling to implement a slider. I basically want to take those images and put them into a simple slider when the window gets below a certain size but I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: I think this will help you: http://scotch.io/bar-talk/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system

Comment: @MichaelParker Thanks, this was very helpful as I haven't used bootstrap in a long time so didn't know about this feature! My friend actually suggested using a jQuery slider with JS to determine whether or not the slider is used or not using a combination of the JS and `@media` in the CSS. This seems a very long way of doing this considering the new features of Bootstrap 3? I can't see any advantages of using a jQuery slider from what you have posted anyway....

Answer (score 1):

May I offer a different approach. Using a simple horizontal scroll - you can find some nice customizable scrollbars out there to make it look a little more fancy. Since it includes images, I didn't do a jsfiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 

    <style>
        body
        {
            width:100%;
        }

        #hold
        {
            width:90%;
            height:300px;
            overflow-x:auto;
            overflow-y:hidden;
        }

        #image_container
        {
            width:920px;        /* equal to total width of all images */
            min-width:480px;    /* minimum for device size */
        }

        #image_container li
        {
            display:inline;
            width:300px;
            height:100%;
            margin:2px;
        }

        #image_container li img
        {
            width:300px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="hold">
        <ul id="image_container">
            <li><img src="../images/slides/bridge.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="../images/slides/road.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="../images/slides/leaf.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great start for me, I have one problem with your code, the `#image_container` width is set to the width of all 3 images, but for some reason I have to set the width of the container a little bit bigger than all 3 for them all to appear on a fully sized window which is strange, this means when the scroll bar begins to take over there's a small gap either side.

Comment: I also looked into sliders, I really like the look of bxSlider, but again, I don't know how to take this code or your code and transform that into a slider gallery unfortunately.

Comment: it needs to be slightly larger because of the margin on the li. you can remove that but then the images butt up next to each other without space.